# Joining String after certain steps

Tags: python, string, list, join

I want to join 2 symbols to my list:

```
L = [[1, 2, -3], [4, 5, -6], [7, 8, -9]]
...
---> 1 2 -3, 4 5 -6, 7 8 -9
A = []
for i in range(len(L)):
    for k in L[i]:
        A.append(str(k))
print(" ".join(A))
---> 1 2 -3 4 5 -6 7 8 -9
```

Now I'm only missing the ", ". Unfortunately I dont know how to insert them. Is there a way to add them with join?

Comment: Im not a python pro =(. Unfortunately I searched over 1 Hour for the answere, without a result. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
L = [[1, 2, -3], [4, 5, -6], [7, 8, -9]]
', '.join(' '.join(map(str,item)) for item in L)
```

output:

```
'1 2 -3, 4 5 -6, 7 8 -9'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should really learn to work with lambda and map. They prooved themselves as very useful for so often.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehensions is generally considered more "Pythonic" than using `map()` and/or `filter()`:

```
>>> L = [[1, 2, -3], [4, 5, -6], [7, 8, -9]]
>>> print(', '.join(' '.join(str(i) for i in l) for l in L))
1 2 -3, 4 5 -6, 7 8 -9
```

Comment: However, `Simple is better than complex`, `Flat is better than nested`, and  `Readability counts` ;-)